# Set location of xticks in a matplotlib scatter plot

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I am trying to create a scatter plot of measurements where the x labels are WIFI channels. By default matplotlib is spacing the labels in proportion to their numerical value. However, I would like them to be spaced uniformly over the scatter plot. Is that possible?

This is basically what my plot code currently looks like:
- where chanPoints is a list of frequencies and measurements is a list of measurements.

```
plt.scatter(chanPoints,measurements)
plt.xlabel('Frequency (MHz)')
plt.ylabel('EVM (dB)')
plt.xticks(Tchan,rotation = 90)
plt.title('EVM for 5G Channels by Site')
plt.show()
```

[image: This is an example of my current output]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Numpy

You may use numpy to create an array which maps the unique items within `chanPoints` to numbers `0,1,2...`. You can then give each of those numbers the corresponding label.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

chanPoints = [4980, 4920,4920,5500,4980,5500,4980, 5500, 4920]
measurements = [5,6,4,3,5,8,4,6,3]

unique, index = np.unique(chanPoints, return_inverse=True)
plt.scatter(index, measurements)

plt.xlabel('Frequency (MHz)')
plt.ylabel('EVM (dB)')
plt.xticks(range(len(unique)), unique)
plt.title('EVM for 5G Channels by Site')
plt.show()
```

[image]

#### Seaborn

If you're happy to use seaborn, this can save a lot of manual work. Seaborn is specialized for plotting categorical data. The `chanPoints` would be interpreted as categories on the x axis, and have the same spacing between them, if you were e.g. using a [`swarmplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/scatterplot_categorical.html). If several points would then overlap, they are plotted next to each other, which may be an advantage as it allows to see the number of measurement for that channel.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn.apionly as sns

chanPoints = [4980, 4920,4920,5500,4980,5500,4980, 5500, 4920]
measurements = [5,6,4,3,5,8,4,6,3]

sns.swarmplot(chanPoints, measurements)

plt.xlabel('Frequency (MHz)')
plt.ylabel('EVM (dB)')
plt.title('EVM for 5G Channels by Site')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Replace `chanPoints` with an `index`.

```
index = numpy.searchsorted(Tchan, chanPoints)
plt.scatter(index, measurements)
```

Then build your `xticks` with the corresponding lables.

```
ticks = range(len(Tchan))
plt.xticks(ticks, labels=Tchan, rotation = 90)
```